# Insert object into a specified index in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Let's say I have a class called `myClass<K,V>`.
In my class I have an `ArrayList` called `myArrayList`.

How would I go about placing something of type `V` into a certain spot in the array list.
For example, trying something like `myArrayList[place] = vThing` doesn't seem to work.

Here's the declaration:`public ArrayList<V> myArrayList[];`. I added `myArrayList.add(place, value);` , but I'm getting an error that says "cannot invoke add(int, V) on the array type ArrayList[]".

I get it now, I was thinking that an arraylist would work like an array, but it appears as though is works more like a list.

Comment: Show us your declaration, and read the error.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(E)

Answer (score 1):

An [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) has an overload for the [`add()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20E%29) method

```
add(int index, E element)
```

for this exact purpose. You cannot access it using square brackets like an array.

Adding a generic type has nothing to do with this (assuming you define your `ArrayList` as `List<V> myArrayList = new ArrayList<>()`).

Responding to your edit. Change

```
public ArrayList<V> myArrayList[]
```

to

```
public ArrayList<V> myArrayList
```

If you put square brackets there, it will consider it.. Hell, I'm not even sure. It's just bad practice. I'm guessing an array of arraylists? Or an arraylist of arrays?

Comment: @user2793388: you can accept it as an answer if you deem it worthy as such.

Answer (score 0):

```
add(int index, E element)
```

Inserts the specified element at the specified position in list. Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices).

Answer (score 0):

I would advice to learn searching in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html (for example) you can find there all available methods.

For example :

```
void    add(int index, E element)
```

Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list.